# How to free up the used port in virtual env

Tags: flask, foreman

I am using virtual env to run flask app and often my local host port does not work and I have to do export PORT=500* . I mean after using foreman start couple of times at a specific port, the port gets engaged and when I try again to start and it tries to connect saying retrying to connect and then fails.

I have to change the port every time I experience this problem. Is there a command by which I can free the port or delete the port.

Answer (score 0):

often happens because foreman doesn't shutdown properly. Try looking to see if there are process still running in the background that  might be using the port. For example, if you use forman to launch a python app, try:

```
ps aux | grep python
```

to see all your running python processes. You can automatically kill all running python process using the following command

```
ps aux | grep python | tr -s ' ' '\t' |  awk '{system("kill " $2)}'
```

but be careful as this will kill all running python processes that you have running.